# PHP isset not working in POST method

Tags: php, post, isset

I tried to make a form with a post method, and i want to check if the fields are filled with isset(). But even if the fields are empty, the isset returns true.

Here is a simplified code: (name of the page: test.php, the post method is directed to itself)

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    echo 'field set';
}   

?>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When you submit, it always echoes 'field set', even if you didn't enter anything in the "test" input.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: the field is set, but empty()

Comment: var_dump() is one of your best friends in your whole PHP career. Try using it on the $_POST superglobal and you will see yourself what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, when you submit the form, the field *is set*, even if *its value* is an empty string.

Comment: just to let you know the value will be always set for the post variable.. you will always need to check `empty`.

Comment: Ok sorry, i thought isset() was also looking if the variable is empty. My bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So check whether `$_POST['test']` is empty or not and try like this

```
if (isset($_POST['test']) && trim($_POST['test']) != '') {
    echo 'field set';
}
```

You can also use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php),but `Note that "0" is also "empty"` and along with it its better to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the inputs to remove spaces. Another way is to check the length of input using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['test']) && trim(strlen($_POST['test'])) > 0) {
    echo 'field set';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try with `empty()` to check blank cause after submit form `$_POST['test']` always found in `isset()` even it's blank. so need to check with `empty()`

```
if (!empty($_POST['test'])) {
    echo 'field set';
}
```

`0` would be empty/blank with checking `empty()`

Comment: Note that "0" is also "empty".

Comment: Thanks ! I just put 웃웃웃웃웃's comment as the answer, but yours is working too !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `empty()` method.try with this code.

ex : `echo !empty($_POST['test']) ? "field set" : ""` ;

Answer (score 0):

It will echo that you field is set because all you are checking for if is the array key `test` exists with `isset()`. As long as you have a field in your form with the name `test`, it will create an empty key, thus resulting in it being set.

What you would rather like is to see if the key is set, and if the key also is empty or not.

This you can do by:

```
if( isset( $key['test'] ) && $key['test'] !== "" ){
    //Do something
}
```